# Updating Version of Jenkins Netbeans Plugin Uses

Tags: netbeans, plugins, jenkins

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Jenkins using NetBeans, which uses [the stapler hudsons Jenkins plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43938/stapler-hudson-jenkins-support) for Jenkins support. However the version of Jenkins it is using is 1.509 when I need 1.580. Is there a way for me to update the Jenkins version the NetBeans plugin is using?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only way to tweak it is to download the source and compile the plugin. But honestly this is not useful, since the next (Jekins and/or NetBeans) update will break it again. The best thing to do is write an email to "Jesse Glick", who is the maintainer of the plugin, see: https://github.com/stapler/netbeans-stapler-plugin/graphs/contributors. The email is on the GitHub page.